# Query through IEnumerable-hidden many-to-many navigation properties without client side evaluation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

### TL;DR

[Multiple](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-2-hiding-as-ienumerable/) [authors](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/mt842503.aspx) suggest better encapsulating navigation collections with read-only public `IEnumerable` projections of private `ICollection` navigation properties, which is supported in EF Core. I attempted to use a similar technique, with read-only projections to traverse many-to-many relationships--but it causes Linq to fall back to client-side evaluation when traversed (which besides being non-performant is disallowed in EF Core 3.0). If this is my chosen public API, is there a way to make these read-only properties navigable such that Linq can turn them into SQL, without changing the API?

### Full Question

I am attempting to make a data model, with EF Core, with the following design goals:

- As much persistence ignorance as possible--at least from the public API perspective
- Restrict navigation collections from being directly changed via the `ICollection` interface
- Keep my public interface to only expose what look like direct many-to-many relationships
- Hide technical IDs, as they have no domain meaning (this one may drop)

A big limitation right now with EF Core is lack of many-to-many relationships without a join entity, but this is supposed to be coming--so I'm trying to hide the join entities, and I'm following the techniques laid out [in this blog post by ajcvickers](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-2-hiding-as-ienumerable/) (and others).

So, for example, I have these (obviously incomplete) 1st-class entities:

```cs
    public class Conversation
    {
        private IEnumerable<Tag> Tags => _joinToTags.Select(jt => jt.Tag);
        public ICollection<ConversationTag> _joinToTags = new HashSet<ConversationTag>();
    }
```

```cs
    public class Tag
    {
        public string Label { get; private set; } = null!;
        // No `Conversations` navigation property if I can help it
    }
```

(Assume the EF mapping code and trivial `ConversationTag` join entity exist and are correct. They seem to work properly except for the problem described below.)

Note that `Tag`s may be associated with a 5+ other entities... so while I *could* have navigation properties back to those entities from within `Tag`, I'm trying to avoid cluttering the API. But, I *do* need to be able to *query* that direction--e.g. find what `Conversations` have a given `Tag`.

**My problem is: this design does not allow me to query efficiently, and tries to fall back to client-side execution, whenever I traverse the `Tags` property.**

For the most part this was working well. However, I just switched to EF Core 3.0 which helpfully exposed some places where my queries against those navigation properties force client-side evaluation (with what would be very poor performance).

For instance, in EF Core 3.0 this integration test code (using the awesome Shouldly library):

```cs
context.Conversations.Count(c => c.Tags.Any(t => t == context.Find<Tag>("In-Person"))).ShouldBe(2);
```

which was working under EF Core 2.1, now blows up with:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Processing of the LINQ expression 'Any<Tag>(
    source: NavigationTreeExpression
        Value: EntityReferenceConversation
        Expression: (Unhandled parameter: c).Tags, 
    predicate: (t) => t == (Unhandled parameter: __Find_0))' by 
        'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either 
        a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See 
        https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 
        for more detailed information.'
```

Which is probably good, because otherwise I think I'd be retrieving every conversation from the DB in production--the reason for this breaking change in EF Core 3.0.

But, how can I get this "query" to work in such a way that it translates to SQL efficiently--without exposing the join entities and generally keeping the design goals above intact?

This *seems* like it should be doable. A number of things I thought might help haven't:

```cs
// Making it IQueryable instead of IEnumerable...maybe the expression tree will bubble up? Nope...
public IQueryable<Tag> Tags => _joinToTags.AsQueryable().Select(jt => jt.Tag);
```

```cs
// Added this IEnumerable<ConversationTag> extension method:
public static class ConversationTagExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tag> Tags(this IEnumerable<ConversationTag> cts)
    {
        return cts.Select(ct => ct.Tag);
    }
}

// And changed the Tags property to:
public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags => _joinToTags.Tags(); // Nope!
```

Notably, these *do* work:

```cs
// Changing _joinToTags to public:
context.Conversations.Count(c => c._joinToTags.Any(ct => ct.Tag == context.Find<Tag>("In-Person"))).ShouldBe(2);
// Added Conversation property:
//  public IEnumerable<ConversationTag> ConversationTags => _joinToTags.AsEnumerable();
context.Conversations.Count(c => c.ConversationTags.Any(ct => ct.Tag == context.Find<Tag>("In-Person"))).ShouldBe(2);
// ^ that surprised me a little bit.
```

Last, this approach *does* work--with many thanks to [this post](https://benjii.me/2018/01/expression-projection-magic-entity-framework-core/) for pointing me in the right direction--but requires me to know to go to an expression for querying:

```cs
    public class Tag
    {
        public string Label { get; private set; } = null!;

    // Added EF mapping for _joinToConversations, but at least it's not part of the public API...
        private ICollection<ConversationTag> _joinToConversations = new HashSet<ConversationTag>();
        public static Expression<Func<Tag, IEnumerable<Conversation>>> ConversationsExpression
        {
            get { return t => t._joinToConversations.Select(jt => jt.Conversation); }
        }
    }
// And now the unit test code is translated to:
context.Tags.Where(t => t.Label == "In-Person").SelectMany(Tag.ConversationsExpression).Count().ShouldBe(2);
```

That last produces this nice, correct SQL query:

```
[Parameters=[@__entity_equality_Find_0_Label='In-Person' (Size = 9)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "Conversations" AS "c"
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM "ConversationTag" AS "c0"
    INNER JOIN "Tags" AS "t" ON "c0"."TagLabel" = "t"."Label"
    WHERE (("c"."Id" = "c0"."ConversationId1") AND "c0"."ConversationId1" IS NOT NULL) 
      AND (("t"."Label" = @__entity_equality_Find_0_Label) AND @__entity_equality_Find_0_Label IS NOT NULL))
```

This solution, or another solution that would involve Expressions or perhaps exposing technical IDs would be acceptable--but it's not very "fluent" for client developers, and it seems like a better one should exist. It seems as though this approach with an Expression could be applied in the other direction, and tied directly to a standard property that returned something directly representing the *result* of the projection... but I can't figure out the right incantation. Rather, it seems any time I use a standard `Tags` property, no matter what it returns, it falls back to client-side evaluation.

Is there a way to construct a `Tags` property that is more naturally usable, that returns something that Linq can process as an expression tree?

*Appendix: There are a few other design goals here that aren't directly relevant but may raise questions. E.g. the `context` above is actually not directly a EF `DbContext`, but a Unit of Work object whose interface provides `IQueryable`s for each entity type... a thin shell over EF... which may not turn out to be practical, but has been serving me well enough so far. So, if you wonder given my design goals why my test code is using EF directly, it actually isn't--though it is intended to exercise the persistence layer to find problems exactly like the one I'm asking about.*

### Day 2 Update

This is wild...but this is another design that works, or at least successfully creates SQL code:

```cs
    public class Conversation
    {
        internal IEnumerable<Tag> Tags => _joinToTags.Select(jt => jt.Tag); 
        //   ^-- NOTE: now internal instead of private... not ideal
        public ICollection<ConversationTag> _joinToTags = new HashSet<ConversationTag>();
    }

    public static class ConversationExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<Conversation> WhereTag(this IQueryable<Conversation> conversations, Expression<Func<Tag, bool>> expression)
        {
            return conversations.Where(c => c._joinToTags.AsQueryable().Select<ConversationTag, Tag>(ct => ct.Tag).Any<Tag>(expression));
        }
    }

// With test code:
context.Conversations.WhereTag(t => t == context.Find<Tag>("In-Person") ).Count().ShouldBe(2);
```

I got there by extending the concept of `IQueryable` extension methods ([found](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/giving-clarity-to-linq-queries-by-extending-expressions/) [many](http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/extension-methods-filter-iqueryable) [places](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/07/extension-method-linq-interface.html) and I can't remember where I saw it first) with the idea of providing a filter expression as a parameter...which much to my surprise, worked pretty easily. Still not to my goal, but might be preferable to the workaround immediately above. (To be fair, *after* I figured this out I found [an article that does something similar](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1241305/LINQ-Part-A-Deep-Dive-Into-a-Queryable-Extension-M).)

I'm also now exploring some additional tools I've found--particularly [DelegateDecompiler](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler) which I agree is [mind blowing](https://daveaglick.com/posts/computed-properties-and-entity-framework)! It seems like this tool may be the best hope for an answer using Plain Old Properties: `Decompile()` my property getter back into an expression--but I can't get it to work with the collection yet...still trying.

I also now better understand the root of the problem, [as explained here](https://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/24/client-side-properties-and-any-remote-linq-provider):

> The problem occurs because these properties can’t be translated and
> sent to the server as they have been compiled into intermediate
> language (IL) and not LINQ expression trees that are required for
> translation by IQueryable implementations. There is nothing available
> in .NET to let us reverse-engineer the IL back into the methods and
> syntax that would allow us to translate the intended operation into a
> remote query.

...Except that was written in 2009, and now DelegateDecompiler does exist, which sounds like exactly what it does do.

I've also found some other tools in the same vein, such as [Linq.Translations](https://github.com/damieng/Linq.Translations), [PropertyTranslator](https://github.com/peschuster/PropertyTranslator) (though that looks likely defunct), [ExpressMapper](http://expressmapper.org/) (and relevant [blog post](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/page/5/)), or maybe even AutoMapper, as I didn't before know about the [Queryable Extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Queryable-Extensions.md) feature. Still haven't found the magic words though.